# Where does/did word-formation in German language happen?

Tags: history

I am interested in a comprehensible overview, summarization where most of word-formation in German language actually happen. How are new words finally accepted to end in an official dictionary like the ***Duden***.

Sources are obviously belletristic fiction, newspapers, music lyrics, local dialects, non-fiction books, scientific literature, and more. Are there any studies visualizing sources and development of sources over time and how this process of word-formation changed since the beginning of the internet especially for the German language. Does anyone here has experience and can elaborate on this.

Some scientists think German is threatened esp. by exterior sources, e.g. anglicisms. How is the ratio of word-formations originating in germany compared to e.g. anglicism. Is there an increase in anglicisms over time?

Comment: Can you name some of these scientists and their fields?

Comment: @hippie http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2011/mar/14/german-language-anglicisms-challenge or simply search for "deutsch wissenschaftssprache schutz anglizismen"...

Comment: Another question where I have to put ma answer into to the comment-box: There are several German resources, hopefully you can understand these: [link](http://www.vds-ev.de/), [link](http://blog.zeit.de/schueler/2010/11/11/sprache-verandert-sich-%E2%80%93-einflusse-auf-das-deutsche/) but if you are really interested in this topic you have to read scientific books, there are several available.

Comment: Another interesting German article: [Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/2007/31/Deutsch-Aufmacher), [Entwicklung der deutschen Sprache](http://www.litde.com/literatur-sprache/entwicklung-der-deutschen-sprache/), [History german Language](http://www.lrz.de/~hr/lang/dt-hist.html)

Comment: @infitesima thx for your effort, you should put it into an answer, i wasnt expecting more than some good links from an insider :) With your current reputation your should be able to answer every question and use as much links as you want, only for new users there is afaik a limit for max. links in a answer to avoid link spamming

Comment: @splattne can probably sort this out

Comment: After I save my StackOverflow Account details to all stackexchange sites I can't answer anymore.

Comment: @infitesima probably your name/account changing from sarah to infi looked like multi-accounting (forbidden afaik)? make a thread on http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/ about it to a mod here or go in the chat. User "splattne" can probably help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem on contributing links to this question is, that the most are in German. It's a research area on it's own. There are associations for rescuing the German language: [vds-ev.de](http://www.vds-ev.de/startseite) or the evolution of the language [Gesellschaft für
deutsche Sprache](http://www.gfds.de/)

The greatest influences nowadays are Anglicisms a few examples: [Kampf gegen die Anglizismen](http://www.rp-online.de/wissen/Der-Kampf-gegen-die-Anglizismen_bid_26072.html)

Interesting articles from "Die Zeit": [Wie sich die deutsche Sprache verändert](http://blog.zeit.de/schueler/2010/11/11/sprache-verandert-sich-%E2%80%93-einflusse-auf-das-deutsche/)

The history and changes of the german language [Entwicklung der deutschen Sprache](http://www.litde.com/literatur-sprache/entwicklung-der-deutschen-sprache/)

Another link to the history (in English) [Short History German Language](http://www.lrz.de/~hr/lang/dt-hist.html)

You can also check the German Wikipedia article on "Deutsch" [Einflüsse anderer Sprachen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache#Einfl.C3.BCsse_anderer_Sprachen_auf_die_deutsche_Sprache)

Linklist from the university of Portsmouth: [Link](http://userweb.port.ac.uk/~joyce1/dialects/histlang.html)

For further readings I recommend scientific books, journals on this topic.